What input is blacklisted on MO?
I wonder whether it could be possible to make public which input is blacklisted in titles, posts, tags here on MathOverflow. Or at least a redacted list - I could understand that the mods might keep some of the blacklisted phrases private. (For example, if some of the blacklisted input is intended to prevent or reduce spam posts and making the complete list would make life easier for the spammers.)
For example, Mathematics Stack Exchange has such list - although it is not clear whether it is maintained: Which are blacklisted tags and blacklisted phrases?
Here on MO, there is only some information available on meta:

For example, some tags that have been blacklisted after a discussion on meta: Should we blacklist or delete the "research" tag? and Is the [completeness] tag necessary?
Recently there was a post which suggests that full stop is blacklisted at the end of the title: Why can't question titles end with a period? (But as you can see in the comments there, it is allowed on other sites.)


Hmmm... Why would anybody care? Is it so often that you try to use some phrase, discover that it is blacklisted, and cannot immediately come with a workaround acceptable to everyone?

@fedja For example, people would know whether something is intentionally blacklisted or whether something is simply a bug. As in one of the threads linked in the question.
